# ValueError with Python and Numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to rebuild a song in python, but I cannot concatenate the notes of the same.
I get this error:

> **ValueError**: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0)
>   (1250)

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def nota(f,d):
    ts = 0.0002
    t  = np.arange(0, d, ts)
    X  = 5500*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
    return X

# II.2.b)
pausa    = nota(0,0)
La       = nota(440,0.25)
Mi       = nota(659.26,0.25)
Do       = nota(253.25,0.25)
Sol      = nota(783.99,0.25)
Si       = nota(493.88,0.25)
Solbemol = nota(830.61,0.25)

def FurElise():
    musica = np.array((pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,pausa,pausa,Mi,Mi,Solbemol,    \
                       pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,pausa,pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,    \
                       pausa,pausa,Mi,Mi,Solbemol,pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,    \
                       pausa,Do,Sol,Do,pausa,pausa,Sol,Sol,Si,pausa,pausa, \
                       La,Mi,La,pausa,pausa,Mi,Mi,Mi,pausa))
    y=0
    for x in musica:
        z=np.hstack((x,y))
        y = y+x
    z=np.hstack((x,y))
    plt.plot(z)
    plt.show()

FurElise()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `x` is an array and `y` is a number if I'm not mistaking …

Comment: Two small points: you should really make the effort to [code in English](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html) (avoiding [Spanish variable names](http://www.codespanish.com/lang_enwhy-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-code-in-spanishlang_enlang_esporque-no-debe-escribir-codigo-en-espanollang_es/)), and you should consult [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable-naming guidelines. It's confusing to see variables and function definitions in CamelCase, for instance.

Comment: My variables are in Portuguese, not in Spanish :)

Answer (score 3):

As @filmor notes, `x` and `y` are of different shapes, and the reason for that is your definition of `pausa = nota(0,0)`. By using a `d` value of `0`, the resulting array is of length `0` while all other arrays are of length `1250`, and `y = y+x` will eventually throw the error you're seeing (e.g. after 3 iterations, given your current definition of `musica`).

Assuming you want the pause to be of the same length as all other notes, you can re-define `pausa` so as to get rid of the error:

```
pausa = nota(0,0.25)
```

Comment: Odd, because merely switching that line of code in your example script solves the issue for me. Are you sure you're not seeing the error in another line of code? Try modifying your example script directly and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You create `musica` (assuming that you've fixed `pausa` as described by @fgb) by stacking the 51 notes as rows in a 2D array.  So, `musica.shape` is `(51, 1250)`

I think that you want `z` to be a long 1D array where all the notes are in one row, instead of each in their own row.  There are two solutions.  One, is to say:

```
musica = np.array((pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,...))
z = musica.flatten()
plt.plot(z)
```

and completely remove all of this:

```
y=0
for x in musica:
    z=np.hstack((x,y))
    y = y+x
z=np.hstack((x,y))
```

A better solution is to make `musica` a 1D array when you create it:

```
musica = np.hstack((pausa,pausa,La,Mi,La,...))
plt.plot(musica)
```

This takes all the notes (`pausa`, `La`, etc) and stacks them ***h***orizontally (so that they're all in one row together), so you never need to flatten or concatenate anything.

Comment: +1 for the second approach (directly `np.hstack()` all notes), which does away with the need for `pausa` to be of a particular length and greatly simplifies the code.

Comment: @fgb Syntactically it doesn't require `pausa` to have finite length, but given the program, I think the `pausa` should still have a finite duration, otherwise it won't even be there.

Comment: I agree with you that it should have some length, but I doubt it'd be a good idea to enforce this to be the same length as all the other notes.